# Remove window title in matplotlib figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Running the following code in a jupyter notebook (python3)

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(9,2.5))
```

The resulting figure is embedded in a window with huge borders that are wasting space. Up to now, I only found a function to set the window title of a figure "canvas.set_window_title". How can the window layout be changed? In particular, how can the window header be removed, the area where the window title and the "Stop Interaction" Button resides?

EDIT: I want to keep the interactive mode of matplotlib.

[Screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7mE4.png).

Answer (score 2):

replace:

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

with

```
%matplotlib inline
```

### Edit:

I see you want to keep interactive... I don't know if it is possible; `inline` is not interactive. You may have to settle for a floating window.

Comment: Thank you, this is the anwer to my question as I posted it. But I want to stay in interactive mode and keep the navigation panel.

Comment: Any updates on this? Can it be made in interactive mode?

Comment: Not to my knowledge... If you need inline interactivity, maybe bokeh (or plotly(?)) will suit you better?

Comment: it might require creating a custom css file to restyle the jupyter layout. I noticed when I installed Jupyter themes, this bar changed slightly. you can get jupyter themes here https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes